# How to pass a function as a prop, when the component is expecting an object?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component

```
<Object 

dropDownProps={{items: [{text: "text", title: "title", prices: { new: 100, old: 100}, disabled: false}]}}
/>
```

This works just fine

But I want to do the following

Create a function like :

```
generarDropDownListaProductos = (lista) => {
    //[{text: "text", title: "title", prices: { new: 100, old: 100}, disabled: false}]

    return {items: [{text: "text", title: "title", prices: { new: 100, old: 100}, disabled: false}]}
  }
```

And then pass the prop as following

```
<Object 

dropDownProps={() => this.generarDropDownListaProductos(empresa.listaProductos)}
/>
```

But it asks for

> Property 'items' is missing in type '() => { items: { text: string;
> title: string; prices: { new: number; old: number; }; disabled:
> boolean; }[]; }' but required in type 'IButtonDropDownProps'

How to fix this without having to pass the whole object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the return value of the function then then call it directly.

```
<Object 
  dropDownProps={this.generarDropDownListaProductos(empresa.listaProductos)}
/>
```

To fix the type mismatch do the following:

```
generarDropDownListaProductos = (lista): IButtonDropDownProps => {
    return {
     items: [{text: "text", title: "title", prices: { new: 100, old: 100}, disabled: false}]
    }
  }
```

Ensure you import the `IButtonDropDownProps` type.

Comment: That way ive to modify the function to   ```return items: [{text: "text", title: "title", prices: { new: 100, old: 100}, disabled: false}]``` , but i cant do that Because ```Cannot find name 'items'.```

Comment: No don't modify the function. Just return the object.

Comment: then if i return the object and i call the function as u stated i still get ```Type '{ items: { text: string; title: string; prices: { new: number; old: number; }; disabled: boolean; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IButtonDropDownProps'.
  Types of property 'items' are incompatible.```

Comment: Then manually type the return value of the function. I'll update with details.

Comment: thx, so missing the interface was the problem

Comment: Yep it is good practice to specify return types for this reason as typescript can make some silly assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your input object as the following

```
const input = { getItems : this.getItems };
private getItems(): Array<any> {
  return [];// place your items here assuming it is static list
}
```

Pass the input object to the component, call it from component as

```
generarDropDownListaProductos = this.input.getItems();
```